# substring-after returning empty string

Tags: python, xpath, substring, lxml

I can't seem to return the substring I need using `substring-after` - here's my code:

```
In [19]: root = et.fromstring('<a><c><b>the.never.ending.tale.99999.gz</b></c></a>')

In [20]: root
Out[20]: <Element a at 0x7f80da3d3bc8>

In [21]: root.xpath('substring-after(./a/c/b, "tale")')
Out[21]: ''
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `root` is an element (I suppose the `a` element) you need the path `c/b` instead of `a/c/b`.